# Create indicator or custom drawing object based on an arbitrary time range

Tags: pine-script

Is there is a way of creating a custom drawing object, or, even better an on-chart indicator, but based on a custom time range, like "Fixed Range Volume Profile"?

For your better understanding of what I want to achieve, I want to be able drawing a rectangle with two (or more) levels above and below and ideally, a "point of control" line (that can’t be achieved with a drawing object, but can be achieved with an indicator).

[image]

Comment: That can be done. See [Pine scripts are now interactive](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-scripts-are-now-interactive-27147/)

Comment: @BjornMistiaen, thank you! It seems that this is what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pine 5 has a built-in box.new function, you can set borders according to your own conditions.
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_box{dot}new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_box%7Bdot%7Dnew)